# PHP Include a file in a included file?

Tags: php, html

I want to include a file in an included file.

I have a file named `acp.php` in the directory `Pages/cms/src/acp`.

In this file I included the file `connect_get_data.php` in the directory `Pages/cms/src/acp/tools`, which is to print the database output for the requested page.

In this file I included the Database connection file which is named `connection.php` in the directory `Pages/cms/src/tools`.

Here are my include statemants:

acp.php - `include("./tools/connect_get_data.php")`;

connect_get_data.php - `include("../../tools/connection.php")`;

and here is the Error it caused:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:
include(../../tools/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Pages\cms\src\tools\connect_get_data.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:
include(): Failed opening '../../tools/connection.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Pages\cms\src\tools\connect_get_data.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:
Undefined variable: db in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Pages\cms\src\tools\connect_get_data.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:
mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Pages\cms\src\tools\connect_get_data.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:
mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Pages\cms\src\tools\connect_get_data.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:
Trying to get property 'Content' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Pages\cms\src\tools\connect_get_data.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:
Undefined variable: db in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Pages\cms\src\tools\connect_get_data.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:
mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Pages\cms\src\tools\connect_get_data.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
```

But if I open the connect_get_data.php in my browser it works fine...

I hope some one her can help me with my issue.

Comment: Use absolute paths in your includes, or use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and use the path from there. By just using dots, it will attempt to access the file relative to the current URL path.

Comment: ^ or the magic constant [\_\_DIR\_\_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#language.constants.predefined.changelog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a path error instead of include("../../tools/connection.php"); use **include("../tool/connection.php")**;.

this will work for you. There is a path error in your code.